# Create an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, file, object

I'm fairly new to java, but I understand programming concepts. I'm working on a trading game. I want to be able to list every item I want in a .txt file and read down the list making an instance of Item() object for each. I know how to read the input, it's then sorting them into an array that is hard to figure out.

Is an array the right way to go for this? Or is there some other way to handle my item information?

```
public class Item {
    File itemList = new File("Items.txt");
    ArrayList<Item> Items = new ArrayList<>();

    String line = "";
    String name = "";
    int price = 0;
    int ID = 0;

    public void setItem (String theName, int thePrice, int theID)
    {
    name = theName;
    price = thePrice;
    ID = theID;
    }
    public void Initialize () throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(itemList);
        do
        {
            do
            {

                line = scan.nextLine();
                while (!line.startsWith("#")) {line = scan.nextLine();}
                if (line.matches(".*\\d+.*"))
                {
                    price = Integer.parseInt(line);
                }else
                {
                    name = line;
                }
            }while(!line.equals(""));
            Items.add(new Item());
            ID++;
        }while (!line.equals("end"));
    }
}
```

Comment: You can go for an array for your Item object. once you read the input, you have to set the values into the variables of a new Item object and append it to an array.

Comment: Java methods and variable names begin (by convention) with a lower case letter. Also, your `Initialize` method should probably be `static`, as should the `Items` list and the `itemList` variable.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can store your items maybe the easiest way is doing it with an array list.

```
ArrayList<Items> items = new ArrayList<Items>();
```

And assuming that you create new items with your input data:

```
/*This goes in a loop where you read in currentInputData*/
items.add(new Item(currentInputData));
```

For further information about manipulating ArrayLists refer to javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try that.

Comment: But  you can't pass data directly into a class right? Wouldn't the array list need to also run my constructor?

Comment: I get an error if I try to pass variables into the new Item

Comment: Firs of all, make your list static, it belongs to class not to object. Second, of course when you add a new Item to your list you have to provide every argument (name price id) in your case. Also Initialize method should be also static there is no need for item objects to have this method. Making it static means that it belongs only to the class. You can reach static members like this ClassName.method() or ClassName.variable.